# Update Table from Reference worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master table that I need clients to be able to update using a worksheet where they will edit a "status", "notes" and "date" column for each target they have set,and then click a button to update the master table.

Both the master table and the worksheet have a target ID value that I intended to use for matching. I would like to be able to loop through the master database and find if there is a matching target ID in the "update" table, and if there is I need to update three columns in the master table from the matching row in the "update" table. I tried writing this loop in VBA but I am stuck on the correct code (I'm very new to VBA).

Here is the code I have:

```
Sub Button4_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = Sheets("Master").ListObjects("MasterTable")

For i = 2 To tbl.Range.Rows.Count

If Sheets("Master").Cells(i, 1) = Sheets("Data Update").Cells(i, 1) Then
Range(Sheets("Data Update").Cells(i, 9), Sheets("Data Update").Cells(i, 11)).Copy
Range(Sheets("Master").Cells(i, 9), Sheets("Master").Cells(i, 11)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

ElseIf Sheets("Master").Cells(i + 1, 1) = Sheets("Data Update").Cells(i, 1) Then
Range(Sheets("Data Update").Cells(i, 9), Sheets("Data Update").Cells(i, 11)).Copy
Range(Sheets("Master").Cells(i, 9), Sheets("Master").Cells(i, 11)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End If
Next i

End Sub
```

It works only if the target ID in the "update" table is in the same row as the  target ID in the "master" table. So, if target ID #1 is in row 1 in both tables it will match, if target ID #2 is in row 2 in both tables it will match, etc. But it won't find the target ID if its out of order and it will stop of the target IDs are not in sequential order

Answer (score 0):

Please see:

```
Sub UpdateTable()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tblMaster As ListObject, tblUpdate As ListObject
    Dim valsReturned(1 To 2) As String
    Dim valToFind As String

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set tblMaster = .Sheets("Master").ListObjects("MasterTable")
        Set tblUpdate = .Sheets("Master").ListObjects("UpdateTable")
    End With

    With tblMaster.DataBodyRange
        For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
            'where is ID to find? please update as required
            valToFind = .Cells(i, 1).Value
            If CheckAndGetTableRow(tblUpdate, valToFind, valsReturned) Then
                .Cells(i, 9).Value = valsReturned(1)
                .Cells(i, 11).Value = valsReturned(2)
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
Function CheckAndGetTableRow(ByRef tblUpdate As ListObject, ByVal valToFind As String, ByRef valsReturned() As String) As Boolean

    Dim i As Integer, tRows As Integer
    Dim success As Boolean

    With tblUpdate.DataBodyRange
        tRows = .Rows.Count
        For i = 1 To tRows
            'Please update if required, now ID is in first column
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = valToFind Then
                'please update as required
                valsReturned(1) = .Cells(i, 9).Value
                valsReturned(2) = .Cells(i, 11).Value
                success = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With

    CheckAndGetTableRow = success

End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: Wow this worked thanks so much (the reference IDs were in the first column as you assumed). I clearly have a lot to learn about vba because I never would have come up with this one! Appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad that it helped. Thanks